# Switch statement for a range not working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am using a switch case in javascript to find a range, but its not working. Have I done something wrong?

```
function mapPriceRange(value){
    var range = '';
    switch(value)
    {
        case (value >= 0 && value <= 25):
            range = '0_25';
            break;
        case (value >= 25 && value <= 40):
            range = '25_40';
            break;
        case (value >= 40 && value <= 60):
            range = '40_60';
            break;
        case (value >= 60 && value <= 100):
            range = '60_100';
            break;
        case (value >= 100 && value <= 150):
            range = '100_150';
            break;
        case (value >= 150 && value <= 200):
            range = '150_200';
            break;
        case (value >= 200 && value <= 300):
            range = '200_300';
            break;
        case (value >= 300 && value <= 500):
            range = '300_500';
            break;
        case (value >= 500 && value <= 1000):
            range = '500_1000';
    }
    return range;
}

console.log(mapPriceRange(500));
```

I am always getting an empty string.

Comment: You need to use if-else

Comment: It's strange that your ranges are overlaping. By this logic value 200 will fall into [150, 200], but it's also in range [200, 300].

Comment: yep ur right, thanks I ll use `if else` and I ll fix my ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `switch(value)` to `switch(true)` and it should work. See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AC8FC/).

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
function checkRange(x, n, m) {
    if (x >= n && x <= m) { return x; }
    else { return !x; }
}

var x = 5;


    function mapPriceRange(value){
        var range = '';
        switch(value)
        {

             case checkRange(x, 0, 25):
                range = '0_25';
                break;
             case checkRange(x, 25, 40):
                range = '25_40';
                break;
             case checkRange(x, 40, 60):
                range = '40_60';
                break;
             case checkRange(x, 60, 100):
                range = '60_100';
                break;
             case checkRange(x, 100, 150):            
                range = '100_150';
                break;
             case checkRange(x, 150, 200):
                range = '150_200';
                break;
             case checkRange(x, 200, 300):
                range = '200_300';
                break;
             case checkRange(x, 300, 500):
                range = '300_500';
                break;
             case checkRange(x, 500, 1000):
                range = '500_1000';
        }
        return range;
    }

    console.log(mapPriceRange(500));
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch cases in Javascript *only* with strings. They coerce any input they receive in either the `switch` or in the `case` to string before comparing it. Hence, your `value.toString()` is getting compared to the "true" and "false" strings in the various cases, which is returning `false` in every case.

Using an `ifElse` ladder is the best way around it and refer to any of the other answers for a possible workaround which relies on returning either `value.toString()` or switch over `"true"` instead of `value`.